# Xcode 4 - brackets { } code syntax

Tags: xcode, templates, syntax, xcode4, brackets

Is there an easy way to change the:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
}
```

To

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
}
```

Is there "checkbox" to change the above behavior without modifying the template files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You'll have to [edit the template files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708164/xcode-change-project-templates), unfortunately.